# How to recreate the view on popping?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a requirement in my app to add a custom new text field in the view controller i.e. View A .
Field details are to be filled in the another view i.e. view B  that is getting pushed when we click add field button .
As of now i am pushing a view on add text field button and when all field details have been filled up again on done button i am  pushing a new instance of previous view controller i.e.View A.
My text field is getting added up but existing all data is removed from rest of the fields on view A.
I tried popping the view on done button  but it does not create new text field on view A although all field data is intact.

So is there any way to recreate a full view on popping so that new text field is created also my data in previous view controller is not lost.

Comment: Please edit your post and clarify what are you doing, in your title it says popping view controller, in your body it says popping views. ViewController != View. In this way it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I simply do not understand your question, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you use push/pop mechanism in UINavigationController previous data never lost. Your controller hierarchy should be like this;

UINavigationController --> FirstViewController --> DetailViewController

**FirstViewController**

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mv animated:YES];
```

**DetailViewController**

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or you can do that on storyboard with connections.

Answer (score 0):

You should pop back to the previous ViewA, so you don't lose the data you entered there, but add a new text field in code when you do. You could create a delegate protocol in ViewB with a method that you call from your done button (you would probably want a flag you can set, so that you only call the method once if you only want to create one text field). The implementation of that method in ViewA would create the text field and add it to the view in the appropriate place.